# Array push to end keeping format

Tags: php, arrays, email

I'm making a automated system to send out emails. I have an array containing info about registered users: their email and forum name/nickname:

```
$array = [
    ['jane.apples@gmail.com', 'Jane Apples'],
    ['jdoe@gmail.com', 'John Doe'],
];
```

To send the emails it uses a for each loop:

```
foreach ($array as list($email, $name)) {
    echo "$email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$name<br>";
}
```

This would yield:

```
jane.apples@gmail.com   Jane Apples
jdoes@gmail.com   John Doe
```

In the final code I would like it to do this:

```
foreach ($array as list($email, $name)) {
    email($email, $name);
}
```

Also, please note that I would like the array in a different file like: `array.php` and then include the file.

Please help me do this, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I've found the solution while messing around a little bit here is the code:

```
<?php 
$result = array();
$file = fopen("mail.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);

  list($email, $name) = explode(":", $line);
  echo $email . ':' . $name .'<br>';

}
fclose($file);
?>
```

The `mail.txt` file looks like:

```
jane.apples@gmail.com:Jane Apples
jdoes@gmail.com:John Doe
```

If you where to use this yourself, edit the part where it echos: `$email . ':' . $name . '<br>';`

Comment: you can accept your own answer using the checkbox (the thing under the down vote) so people will know your question has been resolved.

Comment: @ChrisBanks I know, I had to wait 2 days to do so. :)